# Crystal reports installation in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, crystal-reports, report, eclipse-3.6, helios

I am very new to Crystal Reports but I am familiar with Eclipse as I have made many apps on Android with it. Now I want to generate Crystal Reports in Eclipse Helios (SDK 3.6.2). So for the installation I referred to [`this link`](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-29757). I followed the path for the manual download and successfully downloaded the `SAP Crystal Reports, Version for Eclipse – Manual Installation package`. But I am lost from there.

I followed the steps given in [`this pdf file`](http://downloads.businessobjects.com/akdlm/crystalreportsforeclipse/2_0/CR4E20ViaUpdateService.pdf) and I tried to go on: `help->Install new software...`. But on the final installation it gives the following error:

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
>   Software currently installed: Crystal Reports for Eclipse 2.0.13.r1733 (com.businessobjects.crystalreports.integration.eclipse.feature.feature.group 2.0.13.r1733)
>   Missing requirement: Crystal Reports Runtime Support 12.2.214.r1733 (com.businessobjects.crystalreports.integration.eclipse.facet.shared 12.2.214.r1733) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.jst.common.frameworks 0.0.0' but it could not be found
>   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>   From: Crystal Reports for Eclipse 2.0.13.r1733 (com.businessobjects.crystalreports.integration.eclipse.feature.feature.group 2.0.13.r1733)
>   To: com.businessobjects.crystalreports.integration.eclipse.facet.shared [12.2.214.r1733]

I searched for this error (via Google and stackoverflow) but could not find any solution. Can any one help me?

Comment: I have this exact same problem, the solution below did not help. Did you ever resolve this error?

Comment: @awashburn- I completely uninstalled Crystal Reports from my computer and made a fresh installation of it from Eclipse

Answer (score 1):

I am using Eclipse 32-bit, and I manually installed Crystal Reports package from http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-29757. It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because you are running eclipse 64-bit? If so, try to install the plug-in manually. Download the manual installation package from here: http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-29757

Unzip the files and copy them to eclipse folder then crystal report plug-in should work.

Comment: @Dinh-Thank you so much for replying but I am running eclipse 32-bit.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this http://downloads.businessobjects.com/akdlm/crystalreportsforeclipse/2_0/update_site/ it works for me ;)

Thank you, after all, I realise it works only on 32 bits ...Hum yes I know.